# How to create transparent image for rubber stamp in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have to create an image, which is an overlay texture made up of a white image with some transparency to give it the appearance of a rubber stamp.

For reference see the image "stamp_overlay.png" in the video http://railscasts.com/episodes/374-image-manipulation .

This is what i did:

```
convert -size 70x70 canvas:white stamp_overlay1.png
```

and then

```
convert stamp_overlay1.png -transparent white stamp_overlay1.png
```

But how do I make it like the image?

I am pretty much new to ImageMagick. Any help is highly solicited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Ok, I got that wrong! You want to *create* a stamp overlay, not *overlay* a stamp overlay. You can do that like this:

```
# Create white square, draw a black rectangle, then make black pixels transparent
convert -size 300x300 xc:white                   \
   -fill black -draw "rectangle 20,100 200,280"  \
   -transparent black out.png
```

**Original Answer**

I find your question very hard to understand, but I think I know what you want. First, let's create a solid red image

```
convert -size 70x70 xc:red red.png
```

then let's composite the `stamp_overlay.png` image on top

```
convert red.png stamp_overlay.png -composite out.png
```

which gives this

[image]

but now you want to make the white areas transparent, so you need to do this:

```
convert red.png stamp_overlay.png -composite -transparent white out.png
```

and that still looks the same on this white background, but it isn't :-)

Comment: Hi @Mark, the issue is I have to create stamp_overlay.png. Can we create such an image?

Comment: Please have another look.

Comment: thanks @Mark... These are the steps I follow now: `convert -size 300x300 xc:white                   \
   -fill black -draw "rectangle 20,100 200,280"  \
   -transparent black out.png
` then `convert -size 70x70 xc:red red.png` then `convert red.png out.png -composite -transparent white out.png` but i don't get the effect u show in the image above

Comment: Hi @Mark, as mentioned in the above comment, I tried the steps, but it still didn't create the effect you have shown in the image above, or something similar, which is why I didn't mark it as answer. Though it provided some insights, so I upvoted. I am still not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. In that case I am still not understanding what you really want to do. Can you draw/create whatever it is you want using GIMP or Photoshop so I can see what I am aiming of please?

Comment: I just want to create an overlay similar to that in the video, or for that matter the overlay which you might have used to compose with red ball and display the effect as above. Thanks for the effort you are expending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72215/discussion-between-mark-setchell-and-inquisitive).

Comment: Does this command create a green image with a rectangular transparent hole in it on your machine? `convert -size 300x300 xc:lime -fill black -draw "rectangle 20,100 200,280" -transparent black out.png`

Comment: And his makes a red square, correct? `convert -size 200x200 xc:red red.png`

Comment: And this puts the req square on top in the middle? `convert out.png red.png -gravity center -composite x.png`

Comment: And this makes the red square transparent? `convert out.png red.png -gravity center -composite -transparent red x.png`

Comment: Ok, so what needs to happen to `x.png` to make it like you want?

Comment: Now these are all the transparent squares, you mean to say I would need to create an image with white background, having very tiny pixel shaped transparent areas scattered in that background to make that overlay?

Comment: I think now I got how to implement. Thanks so much

Comment: Great - glad we got there! Questions are free, so if you have any more, just ask a new question. There are lots of talented people on SO who can help you out. Good luck!